# get new line after input element javascript

Tags: javascript

I am dynamically adding input elements so user can input emails.  I need each input element (which is inserted after a button) to be on a separate line.  Here is the function:

```
function feMail()
{
var element = document.createElement("Input");
element.setAttribute("type", "text");
document.body.appendChild(element);
linebreak = document.createElement("br");
element.appendChild(linebreak);
}
```

I tried the linebreak above, but it is not working. Just a beginner coder here so thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You should append the linebreak to `document.body`, not `element`. The element you are creating looks like this:

```
<input type="text">
    <br>
</input>
```

The last line should instead be `document.body.appendChild(linebreak);`.